# Have not kept in touch with former boss. Can I reach out to ask for reference?

Tags: professionalism, references, employment-gaps

I left my job one year ago to care for disabled loved one. Due to life changes, I may be headed back to the work place in another year or so. I have not spoken to my previous boss or other supervisor since. I did ask both at the time if I could keep in touch but neither of us did.

Can I go back now and ask for references, and how do I present that? I did leave on great terms.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your input and kind words.

Comment: Related: [How to resume contact with a former manager who I haven't talked to for 3 years?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6254/141)

Answer (score 15):

Of course you can. You left for (just about) the best reason possible, nobody even vaguely reasonable would not write you a reference under those circumstances. Doesn't matter if you haven't kept in touch, you had far more important things to worry about.

Comment: To add to this answer a little, it's extremely common to fall out of touch with former coworkers even when you don't have such an extremely good reason as the OP. Nobody is going to be mad to hear from you!